# WCF Exposing service with http and https using BasicHttpBinding Certificate still says NotSecure in browser

Tags: c#, wcf, x509certificate, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I am exposing a single WCF service with two endpoints both on BasicHttpBinding. However, one for http and one for secure (SSL). I am successful in achieving that using the below.

In IIS, I also configured the default development certificate in the site SSL and clicked the "Require SSL" and clicked Ignore/Accept which is fine.

**My Issue:**

I see that when I use the https call in the browser, I see that "Not Secure" warning and you click to proceed and it is in red but with https. When I click on the Not Secure button, I see certificate invalid. Is there anything I need to do in browser or the certificate config below in the server behavior should go to endpoint behavior?

[image]

```
 <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="myServiceBehavior" name="MyService">

         <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="IInvoiceService"/>
         <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="myBinding" contract="IInvoiceService"/>
      </service>
  </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="myBinding" >          
          <security mode="Transport">
           <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>
          </security>
        </binding>        
      </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>


<behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="graph">
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="myServiceBehavior">
       <serviceCredentials>
      <serviceCertificate findValue="localhost" storeLocation="LocalMachine"
        storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
      <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Windows" />
    </serviceCredentials>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the certificate to the Trusted People (on which ever client is accessing the service) store for the local machine. Once it is installed in the trusted peoeple store, double click it to see if there are any other errors.

`<serviceCertificate`
Use this element to specify an X.509 certificate that will be used to authenticate the service to clients

> using Message security mode

. If you are using a certificate that will be periodically renewed, then its thumbprint will change. In that case, use the subject name as the x509FindType because the certificate can be reissued with the same subject name.

Comment: Hi, thank you, it worked magically. But I have few quesries for my learning. I couldn't see "Trusted People" in google chrome to view the imported certificate. Why? I could only see Trusted publisher, untrusted publisher etc. Also, how does in general all clients would use or import this certificate? Practically speaking. I never did these certificates, please apologize silly questions

Comment: Also, one another thing I just observed that, I removed the following code from config file, it still works? How? It is not required? <serviceCertificate findValue="localhost" storeLocation="LocalMachine"
        storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
      <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Windows" />
    </serviceCredentials>

Comment: Also, made the clientCredentialType as None in Transport Security in binding configuration. Earlier I made it Certificate. It still works? How come? Only for Basic and Windows it fails now. That is fine.

Comment: Another question, why is that calling by servername instead of localhost again throw the not secure error? Is there any rectification for that? I tried adding hostname in the IIS 443 binding, still no luck....

Comment: @Learner I will try to answer what I can. In order to see your certicate stores you really need to use MMC with the certificate snap-in, Chrome or IE may not place the cert correctly (just my experience.) Regarding the service behavior, since you are specifying `<transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"/>` and not <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" /> it is not using that information.  `serviceCertificate` is for message credentials specified in the binding, in which case the client will have to pass the certicate in the request, and you would need to validate that it is correct.

Comment: thank you. I also found a link or reason for the hostname or ip error, i am convinced with the explanation there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34264559/ssl-certification-works-with-localhost-but-not-computer-name-or-ip

Comment: @Learner not real sure about calling via server name vs. localhost, there are a lot of factors at play here. If you using a proxy, then you have to add the domain to your list of exceptions in IE internet options to bypass proxy, (may not be your case), Like I said there are a lot of factors in play here. Ah just saw your reply, yes if the cert is self signed created in IIS then it might have CN of local host. You can always use makecert  to make your own self signed certs

Comment: Thanks, I think its the certificate naming issue (Domain or subject name or CN)...but I couldn't create one that works successfully...anyway its all great help and learning from you on the red error part on localhost.

Comment: @Learner Glad I could help some, good luck and happy coding. :) PS, I had posted an answer to one of your other question a while back was it helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53697652/2016162

Comment: popo, thank you for your help :) Yes, that was helpful and I could get that sorted too. I am business analyst by innate skills and mindset lol not of programming, but just for bread with no other options I am trying to code :D but computer programming is fun lol. It takes bend out of me :(